# ruby rbenv gem not found

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

In my project I

```
require 'log4r'
```

but I get the following error message when running `ruby app.rb`

```
/Users/mattw/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- log4r (LoadError)
from /Users/mattw/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/mattw/projects/placetel/config/initializers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mattw/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/mattw/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from app.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

If I do `bundle show` it'll give me:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
* bundler (1.10.6)
* curb (0.8.1)
* log4r (1.1.10)
* nori (1.1.3)
```

I am running ruby 2.1.3 locally with rbenv 0.4.0 and bundler 1.10.6

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` after `log4r` was added to the `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize bundler with

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

More info on setup at http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundler_setup.html